# Overriden equality operator is never called

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, cil

The methods of this class

```
public class NullTester
{
    public bool EqualsNull<T>(T o) where T : class
    {
        return o == null;
    }

    public bool IsNull<T>(T o) where T : class
    {
        return o is null;
    }

    public bool EqualsCall<T>(T o) where T : class
    {
        return object.Equals(o, null);
    }
}
```

[compile into this IL code:](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDYB8ACBmAAhwCYCBhAWACgDaCBvau5ow4Ae3YwIFEBHAK4QMUAHICMGADwAVAHwAKGQXYBKAgHcAFojgFlIIsSYtajGqZY4A7CoIBeewQB2EjAG4TpgL7UvVtk5uAEkxN1lFZTVNHQQ9AyN/ZnNLK1t2AjQoFzdPCx8/fICCDi5eQWEoMmFpeSUVdW1dfQJDEiS6FNS6GxVgACs4AGMYADp+IREFdiQcyVU81N8i5aA===)

```
.method public hidebysig 
    instance bool EqualsNull<class T> (
        !!T o
    ) cil managed 
{
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.1
    IL_0001: box !!T
    IL_0006: ldnull
    IL_0007: ceq                                                          // IMPORTANT
    IL_0009: ret
} // end of method C::EqualsNull

.method public hidebysig 
    instance bool IsNull<class T> (
        !!T o
    ) cil managed 
{
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.1
    IL_0001: box !!T
    IL_0006: ldnull
    IL_0007: ceq                                                          // IMPORTANT
    IL_0009: ret
} // end of method C::IsNull

.method public hidebysig 
    instance bool EqualsCall<class T> (
        !!T o
    ) cil managed 
{
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.1
    IL_0001: box !!T
    IL_0006: ldnull
    IL_0007: call bool [mscorlib]System.Object::Equals(object, object)   // IMPORTANT
    IL_000c: ret
} // end of method C::EqualsCall
```

---

So far, so good. 
**But neither `ceq` nor `System.Object::Equals(object, object)` take a possibly overridden `op_Equality` or `Object.Equals` into account.**

Why is that? Why do none of the three proposed ways call `operator==` or an overridden `Equals` method? Shouldn't `System.Object::Equals(object, object)` automatically call any overridden `Equals` method?

---

**EDIT:**
The class I used for test purposes looks like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
     public static bool operator ==(MyClass m1, MyClass m2) => throw new Exception();

     public static bool operator !=(MyClass m1, MyClass m2) => throw new Exception();

     public override bool Equals(object obj) => throw new Exception();
}
```

and neither of the three methods below call any of `MyClass`'s overriden members:

```
NullTester tester = new NullTester();
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(); 

tester.IsNull(myClass);
tester.EqualsNull(myClass);
tester.EqualsCall(myClass);
```

Comment: To my opinion it seems like bad design trying to change the outcome of an object compare with the == operator to null. Other programmers that will use your code might get confused.

Comment: @Neijwiert you're right, but I don't want to change anything, I just want to know why an overriden `operator==` or the `Equals` method is not called by any of `o is null`, `o == null` or `Equals(o, null)`.

Comment: Why do you believe object.Equals(a, b) doesnt call the overriden method of a? - looking at the source code of `public static bool Equals(Object objA, Object objB)` it should https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,f2a579c50b414717,references

Comment: @RandRandom it might be a problem with my code, but no debugger breakpoint in the `Equals` method was hit. Also, I changed the `Equals` method to `public override bool Equals(MyClass o, MyClass o2) => throw new Exception();` which wasn't called either.

Comment: Can you show your code, if possible a mcve would be nice. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @RandRandom thank you for the comment. Please see my edit now.

Comment: @Mardukar no, it's not a copy & paste error. Despite `MyClass` not inheriting any class explicitly, it inherits `Object` by design and therefore I can override the operators and the `Equals` method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The point of generics is: they aren't "templates". The exact same IL needs to run for all `T`. This means that since there are no constraints on `T` in your example, the only operators that are known in the IL are the operators that exist for `object`, so `==` means reference equality, the same as `(object)x == (object)y`.

Polymorphism, however, *does* work. So your `override` on `object.Equals(object)` should work fine. But: it you use `object.Equals(x, y)` (the static method) - it does an *earlier* check for `null`, *before* it calls your method. It *knows* that `null` and "not null" are not semantically equals. If you don't want that: don't use the static `object.Equals(x, y)`.

The static `Equals` method you are using could be expressed:

```
public static bool Equals(object objA, object objB) => 
    ((objA == objB) || (((objA != null) && (objB != null)) && objA.Equals(objB)));
```

So: (same reference, or both null), or (both not null, and `x.Equals(y)`)

This implementation avoids issues where unusual implementations of `x.Equals(y)` could have things like `Equals(a, b) // true` but `Equals(b, a) // false`

Comment: thank you for mentioning the earlier checks, that really explains why I experience this behavior.

Comment: I'm going to remember this with *"equality operator overloads are not polymorphic"* as far as generics are concerned. But what about cases without generics (like a derived instance being passed as an argument to a base class parameter)? Are they polymorphic then? And what about overloads of the other operators?

Comment: @Sefe polymorphism should *always* work; if method is callable (even when using generics with a type constraint on the `T`), then the most concrete `override` (if you see what I mean) should be called. If it isn't: congratulations, you broke the type system and found a CLR bug :)

Comment: Well, polymorphic *methods* should work, sure. But my question is: are *operator overloads* polymorphic? Unlike methods, they are not in this generic scenario. But are they in the other cases I have described?

Comment: @Sefe operator overloads are ***never*** polymorphic; edit: slight caveat: `dynamic` behaves in a way *like* polymorphism, but that isn't really polymorphism so much as per-type runtime resolution

Comment: So the whole issue can be boiled down to one point: *"operator overloads are not polymorphic"*. They are the equivalent to `new`, not to `override`.

Comment: @Sefe yep, basically